# How to change string position within line from text file?

Tags: python, string

I am having a bit of trouble changing position of some words in specific lines from text file look like this:

```
product  name="anything" s_c="7" act_ferq="UREWUERWERU" sys_name="mhr22:21140017-21140076"
common name="xyz" value="1234"
common

product  name="anything" s_c="7" control_type="pos" act_ferq="UREWUERWERU" 
sys_name="mhr22:21140017-21140076"
common name="xyz" value="1234"
common

product  name="anything" s_c="7" act_ferq="UREWUERWERU" sys_name="mhr22:21140016-21140079"
common name="xyz" value="1234"
common

product  name="anything" s_c="7" control_type="neg" act_ferq="UREWUERWERU" 
sys_name="mhr22:21140017-21140076"
common name="xyz" value="1234"
common
```

I want it to look like:

```
product  name="anything" sys_name="mhr22:21140017-21140076 act_ferq="UREWUERWERU" s_c="7"
common name="xyz" value="1234"
common


product  name="anything" sys_name="mhr22:21140017-21140076" control_type="pos" 
common name="xyz" value="1234"
common

product  name="anything" sys_name="mhr22:21140016-21140079 act_ferq="UREWUERWERU" s_c="7"
common name="xyz" value="1234"
common


product  name="anything" sys_name="mhr22:21140017-21140076" control_type="neg"
common name="xyz" value="1234"
common
```

I am working on it by using python regex here's what I am following (pseudocode):

```
filein=open('inputfile.txt','r')
fileout=open('fileout.txt','w')

for line in filein.readlines():
    if re.search('product  name="[^\s]+"',line):
        if "control_type" in line:
            delete  s_c="7" & act_ferq="UREWUERWERU"
            and rearrange line
           (#like this# product  name="anything" sys_name="mhr22:21140017-21140076" 
control_type="neg")
        else:
            rearrange line 
            print (line)
            (#like this# #product  name="anything" sys_name="mhr22:21140017-21140076 
act_ferq="UREWUERWERU" s_c="7")
```

sorry if this kind of question is already been asked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get this by following approach:

```
for line in text.splitlines():
if re.search(r'product  name="[^\s]+"', line):
    change=line.split()
    print(change[0]+' '+change[1]+' '+change[4]+' '+change[3]+' '+change[2])
    print(line)
else:
    print(line)
```